# Converting a number from N to 0 in binary

Tags: algorithms, bit-manipulation

Trying to solve this problem since 2 days. Still unable to figure out even a basic approach.

Given a number $N$ in binary ($1$ to $10^5$), we need to convert it to $0$ using only 2 operations. Given a binary value of a number with length $M$ ($0$ indexed), we can:

1. flip the $i$th bit from $0$ to $1$ or $1$ to $0$ only if the $(i+1)$th bit is 1 and all bits at positions from $i+2$ to $M-1$ are NOT $1$, or
2. flip the rightmost bit unconditionally.

So the problem is to figure out the minimum number of steps to do the conversion.

For example: 
if $N=8$, 
then its binary representation is $1000$.

So to convert $1000$ to $0000$, the following steps apply:

```
1 -  1001 (flipping the rightmost bit unconditionally).  
2 -  1011 (flipping bit at position 2 as bit at position 3 = 1 and there are no more 1 after it. There are no more characters infact. It is the last character).  
3  - 1010 (flipping the rightmost bit unconditionally).  
4  - 1110 (flipping the 1st bit as 2nd bit is 1 and no other bits after that are 1)  
5  - 1111 (flipping the last bit unconditionally).  
6  - 1101 (flipping 2nd bit as 3rd bit is 1 and no other 1 after 3rd bit).  
7  - 1100 (flipping the last bit unconditionally).  
8  - 0100 (flipping 0th bit as 1st bit is 1 and no other 1 after 1st bit).  
9  - 0101 (flipping the last bit unconditionally).  
10 - 0111 (flipping 2nd bit as 3rd bit is 1 and no other 1 after 3rd bit).  
11 - 0110 (flipping the last bit unconditionally).  
12 - 0010 (flipping 1st bit as 2nd bit is 1 and no other 1 after 2nd bit).  
13 - 0011 (flipping last bit unconditionally).  
14 - 0001 (flipping 2nd but as 3rd bit is 1 and no other bit after 3rd bit).  
15 - 0000 (flipping last bit unconditionally).
```

So the result is $15$ as it took $15$ steps.

Unable to solve this problem. Please help.

Comment: It seems the two operations are actually the same. The second one is the same as the first one when $i$ is the LSB and you consider the condition on the bits $>i$ (of which there are none) to be vacuous.

Comment: @Apass.Jack what?

Comment: "consider a binary value of a number with length M (0 indexed)". Did you mean with length 1000 in the example?

Comment: @Apass.Jack No. Just the length of the binary string (char array) is M. And the array is 0 indexed.

Comment: "For example: If N=8. Then M=1000." Did you mean the binary representation of $8$ is 1000? Then it should be clearer if the symbol $M$ is not used here.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just do a simple breadth-first-search on this. First note that:

- There's only one way to do move #1 (you can perform move #1 in one place, if it's at all possible), and doing it multiple times wouldn't result in a loop.
- It doesn't make sense to do move #2 twice in a row.

The important thing to do while searching is to note whether the number we've arrived at was by doing move #2 (otherwise we'd get stuck in a loop). So here's a pseudocode:

- Put the current number into a queue with flag 0
- While the dequeued number is not zero:

  - If you can do move #1 on the dequeued number then do move #1 and put that in a queue with flag 0
  - If the dequeued number's flag is 0, then do move #2, and put that in the queue with flag 1

Comment: Hey! What if the dequeued number has flag 0 and I am still able to do move #1? Shall I do both moves and push them in the queue? How is it going to work with number 29? When N=29 and M=11101?

Comment: The two if statements are not linked. If you can do both then you should enqueue both.

Answer (score 1):

First, we have some basic observations:

1. The minimum number of steps to convert $N$ to $0$ equals to the minimum number of steps to convert $0$ to $N$.
2. To convert $0$ to $N$, the optimal way would be to apply Operation 1 and 2 alternatively.

Now consider the bit sequence $b_1\ldots b_m0$. After performing Operation 1 and 2 alternatively, we get

$$b_1\ldots b_m0\rightarrow b_1\ldots b_m1\rightarrow c_1
\ldots c_m1\rightarrow c_1\ldots c_m0\rightarrow d_1\ldots d_m0\rightarrow d_1\ldots d_m1\rightarrow\cdots$$

where $c_1\ldots c_m$ is the bit sequence obtained by applying Operation 1 on $b_1\ldots b_m$ and $d_1\ldots d_m$ is the bit sequence obtained by applying Operation 2 on $c_1\ldots c_m$. Note every time we perform two operations, one operation is applied on the sequence of the first $m$ bits. That is to say, if we denote by $f(x_1\ldots x_m)$ the minimum number of steps to convert $0\ldots 0$ to $x_1\ldots x_m$, then we have

$$f(x_1\ldots x_m)=2f(x_1\ldots x_{m-1}) +\text{the number of the rest steps to convert the last bit to }x_m.$$

Easy to see the number of the rest steps to convert the last bit to $x_m$ depends on the parity of $f(x_1\ldots x_{m-1})$. If $f(x_1\ldots x_{m-1})$ is even, after performing $2f(x_1\ldots x_{m-1})$ operations, the last bit is $0$, so the number of the rest steps to convert the last bit to $x_m$ is exactly $x_m$. Otherwise, it is $1-x_m$.

Now it is sufficient to use the recurrence above to calculate the minimum number of steps to convert $N$ to $0$ in $O(\log N)$ time if you don't care the detailed operation sequence.

Finally, for fun, you can prove using mathematical induction:

$$f(x_1\ldots x_m)=x_12^{m-1}+(x_1\oplus x_2)2^{m-2}+(x_1\oplus x_2\oplus x_3)2^{m-3}+\cdots+(x_1\oplus\cdots\oplus x_m).$$